# Amazon Simplify manage user hierarchy with cognito and dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I would like to use the AWS Cognito groups with Owner-based scope dynamoDB to manage my users permissions, but there are some particularities:

Lets say I have "Group A" and "Group B" created on my Cognito:
Group A can:

- create a new user, but the new user would be in Group B only
- see and update his own data ( I can manage it with Owner-based scope on tables)
- see and update only users from group B that he created
- give permission to user from group B to see specific data (here is where Owner-based doesnt work, since 2 or more users from group be should be able to see it, not only the owner. ALso, not all users from group be could see, only the selected ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unfortunately it is not possible to do what I was looking for, the Amazon Amplify is a great tool, but to basic app, where you only need a simple way to give access to users see and edit their own content.